# Asynchronous webserver in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Have a Node webserver(webserver.js) which serves file to clients browser. This webserver uses my file and api `require("google-calendar.js");`.

What is best practise to serve the google calendar result from Node to the webbrowser?

The webbserver wants to send pages syncronized but the google-api runs asynchronized which currently means result is showing up once the page is reloaded.

Below is the current code for doing this. All kind of feedback is appreciated.

www/index.html:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
            <iframe type="text/html" src="calendar.html"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

www/calendar.html:

```
CONTENT GENERATED BY webserver.js
```

webserver.js:

```
var port = 9800;
var serverUrl = "127.0.0.1";

var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var fs = require("fs");
var url = require('url');
var checkMimeType = false;
var calendar = require('./google-calendar');

console.log("Starting web server at " + serverUrl + ":" + port);

var calPage = "";

function setCalendarPage(content) {
    calPage = content;
    console.log("Setting calendar content: " + calPage);
}

http.createServer(function(req, res) {

    calendar.getEvents(setCalendarPage);

    var request = req;
    var filename = req.url;
    console.log("====================");
    console.log(filename);
    if (filename == '/') {
        filename = "/index.html";
    }
    sendFile(filename, res);

}).listen(port, serverUrl);

function getMimeType(filename) {
    var ext = path.extname(filename);

    var validExtensions = {
        ".html": "text/html",
        ".js": "application/javascript",
        ".css": "text/css",
        ".txt": "text/plain",
        ".jpg": "image/jpeg",
        ".gif": "image/gif",
        ".png": "image/png",
        ".woff": "application/font-woff",
        ".woff2": "application/font-woff2"
    };
    return validExtensions[ext];
}

function sendFile(filename, res) {
    var localPath = __dirname;
    localPath += ("/www" + filename);
    fs.exists(localPath, function(exists) {
        if (exists) {
            let mimeType = getMimeType(filename);
            getFile(localPath, res, mimeType);
        } else {
            console.log("File not found: " + localPath);
            res.writeHead(404);
            res.end();
        }
    });
}

function getFile(localPath, res, mimeType) {
    fs.readFile(localPath, function(err, contents) {
        if (!err) {

            if (mimeType != undefined) {
                res.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
            }
            res.statusCode = 200;

            if (localPath.includes("calendar")) {
                var calContent = getHtmlPage(calPage);
                res.setHeader("Content-Length", calContent.length);
                res.end(calContent);
            } else {
                res.setHeader("Content-Length", contents.length);
                res.end(contents);
            }
        } else {
            res.writeHead(500);
            res.end();
        }
    });

    function getHtmlPage(text) {
        var html = '<html><head>';
        html += '<meta charset="UTF-8">';
        html += '<title></title>';
        html += '</head>';
        html += '<body>';
        html += text;
        html += '</body>';
        html += '</html>';
        return html;
    }
}
```

google-calendar.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const mkdirp = require('mkdirp');
const readline = require('readline');
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const OAuth2Client = google.auth.OAuth2;
const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly'];
const TOKEN_PATH = 'credentials.json';

var result = "";

// Load client secrets from a local file.
module.exports = {
  getEvents : function (callback){
    if(result != ""){
      return;
    }
  fs.readFile('client_secret.json', (err, content) => {
    if (err) return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
    // Authorize a client with credentials, then call the Google Drive API.
    return authorize(JSON.parse(content),callback);
  });
  }
};


/**
 * Create an OAuth2 client with the given credentials, and then execute the
 * given callback function.
 * @param {Object} credentials The authorization client credentials.
 * @param {function} callback The callback to call with the authorized client.
 */
function authorize(credentials,callback) {
  const {client_secret, client_id, redirect_uris} = credentials.installed;
  const oAuth2Client = new OAuth2Client(client_id, client_secret, redirect_uris[0]);

  // Check if we have previously stored a token.
  fs.readFile(TOKEN_PATH, (err, token) => {
    if (err) return getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback);
    oAuth2Client.setCredentials(JSON.parse(token));
    return listEvents(oAuth2Client, callback);
  });
}

/**
 * Get and store new token after prompting for user authorization, and then
 * execute the given callback with the authorized OAuth2 client.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} oAuth2Client The OAuth2 client to get token for.
 * @param {getEventsCallback} callback The callback for the authorized client.
 */
function getAccessToken(oAuth2Client, callback) {
  const authUrl = oAuth2Client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type: 'offline',
    scope: SCOPES,
  });
  console.log('Authorize this app by visiting this url:', authUrl);
  const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout,
  });
  rl.question('Enter the code from that page here: ', (code) => {
    rl.close();
    oAuth2Client.getToken(code, (err, token) => {
      if (err) return callback(err);
      oAuth2Client.setCredentials(token);
      // Store the token to disk for later program executions
      fs.writeFile(TOKEN_PATH, JSON.stringify(token), (err) => {
        if (err) console.error(err);
        console.log('Token stored to', TOKEN_PATH);
      });
      callback(oAuth2Client);
    });
  });
}

/**
 * Lists the next 10 events on the user's primary calendar.
 * @param {google.auth.OAuth2} auth An authorized OAuth2 client.
 */
function listEvents(auth, callback) {
  result = "";
  const calendar = google.calendar({version: 'v3', auth});
  calendar.events.list({
    calendarId: 'primary',
    timeMin: (new Date()).toISOString(),
    maxResults: 10,
    singleEvents: true,
    orderBy: 'startTime',
  }, (err, {data}) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const events = data.items;
    if (events.length) {
      console.log('Upcoming 10 events:');
      events.map((event, i) => {
        const start = event.start.dateTime || event.start.date;
        console.log(`${start} - ${event.summary}`);
        result += `${start} - ${event.summary} <br>`;
      });
      callback(result);
    } else {
      console.log('No upcoming events found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: can you show your code ? so I can tweak into it ?

Comment: you can use promises or async / await to wait for asynchronous `google-api` https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-make-an-async-function-synchronous

Comment: @UsmanRana Felt like a bit to much of code but now added. Did not figure out which key parts that was needed for help...